# How to write a simple VTune wrapper script on Windows?

Tags: batch-file, anaconda, profiling, python-extensions, intel-vtune

### Question

How do I write a wrapper script for VTune for Windows?

The [documentation](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/vtune-profiler/user-guide/2023-1/analysis-target-options.html#ADVANCED_OPT) provides a simple wrapper script example for bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Prefix script
echo "Target process PID: $VTUNE_TARGET_PID"

# Run VTune collector
"$@"

# Postfix script
ls -la $VTUNE_RESULT_DIR
```

However, on Windows this does not work, of course. I know how to write a batch script with the things I want do prior to the program. However, I fail to formulate the `Run VTune collector` part for batch files.

The documentation says

> use "$@" or "$*" to pass all arguments into the script and start VTune Profiler collection in this environment

Neither `%%@%%`, `%%*%%`, `%%$@%%`, `%%$*%%` worked ("command not found"). How do I get the profiler to start?

### Motivating problem

I want to profile a C++ Python extension in VTune. VTune seems to work quite nicely with python. However, I need to load an anaconda environment prior to calling python. This is what I want to do with the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows equivalent of bash's `$@` is `%*`.